# range.value = [combination string and cell reference]

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a paragraph which is included in a spreadsheet.  I also have a cell reference within the paragraph.  I can format the cell reference in the spreadsheet using the '&' operator, but I need to format it with VBA.

This is what I have inside of my subroutine:

```
Range("A53").Value = "'=Prices quoted  are  firm for  '&Q3&'  days  from  date of quotation for delivery  within  6  months, unless  specifically'"
```

I've tried several different variations of this with no luck.  Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried Range.Formula ?

Comment: @Seb, Yes.  It gives the same result: either a runtime error or printing the literal cell reference on the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `.Formula` instead of `.Value` on the range:

```
Range("A53").Value = """=Prices quoted  are  firm for  "" & Q3 & ""  days  from  date of quotation for delivery  within  6  months, unless  specifically"""
```

Also, double quotes ("") when already inside quotes turn into a single quotes. That can get kind of nasty looking, so you could also use `chr(34)` like:

```
Range("A53").Value = chr(34) & "=Prices quoted  are  firm for " & chr(34) & " Q3 & " & chr(34) & "  days  from  date of quotation for delivery  within  6  months, unless  specifically" & chr(34)
```

Which, in this case is probably even nastier looking so I'm not sure why I mentioned it.

Comment: thanks but these aren't working very well.  I'm still getting quotes and all printing onto the spreadsheet.

Comment: @mistersister - maybe something closer to `Range("A53").Formula = "=" & Chr(34) & "Prices quoted  are  firm for " & Chr(34) & "&Q3&" & Chr(34) & " days from date of quotation for delivery within 6 months, unless specifically" & Chr(34)`.

Comment: Thanks @jeeped! That just got ugly.

Comment: you can escape quote using '""' (double quote) for example : `Range("A53").Formula = "=""Prices quoted are firm for.....`